# JSF expression in attribute of raw HTML element

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I need to put some raw HTML tags into my JSF page because JSF cannot produce the HTML I need. Now I need to evaluate an expression in there:

```
<input type="button" data-ltuId="#{LTU.id}" [...] />
```

JSF does not evaluate this expression. Why? It does evaluate

```
<h:outputText value="#{LTU.id}" />
```

How can I put the result of this expression into `data-ltuId`?

Answer (score 0):

In JSF 1.2 you can't use jsf el (#{}) in plain html template text. It is possible since JSF 2 with Facelets.

I think you can use here JSP el (replace # with $).

```
<input type="button" data-ltuId="${LTU.id}" [...] />
```